# Pass value through jobs in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I try to pass value through my jobs in Azure DevOps pipeline and I use for it this code:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'
stages:
- stage: Processing
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $someValue = 1234
            Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=someValue; isOutput=true;]$someValue")

  - job: B
    dependsOn: ['A']
    variables: 
      someValue: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setVariable.someValue'] ]
    steps: 
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-host "Hello there"
          echo $(someValue)
```

As a result I get this:
[image]

What do I wrong? What code do I need for passing value?

Comment: Your syntax for accessing the task output is wrong. Did you refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks)?

Comment: Most importantly you need to name your task in Job A, and reference that in the variables section in Job B, like $[ dependencies.A.outputs['TaskName.somevar'] ] in which TaskName is the name you give to the task in Job A and somevar is the name of the variable you set in the task. In your example that would be "SomeValue" which is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test your YAML sample and reproduce the same issue.

From your YAML code, it has the following issues.

1.When you set the variable in Powershell task, the command has an extra space character in the command.

Refer to the following sample to set variable:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someValue;isOutput=true;]$someValue"
```

2.You need to define the name of the PowerShell task which is used to set the variable. Then you can use the name in next job to get the variable. `name: taskname`

Here is an full example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'
stages:
- stage: Processing
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: taskname
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $someValue = 1234
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someValue;isOutput=true;]$someValue"

  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    variables: 
      someValue: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['taskname.someValue'] ]  
    steps: 
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-host "Hello there"
          echo $(someValue)
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Share variables across pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#share-variables-across-pipelines)

Comment: Is it possible to share variables between jobs in a classic build pipeline?